# Increase the height of the textarea for comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

Since you can write more. It's harder to do a quick overview of what you've written. So how about increasing the height of the comment textarea from 60px to 90-100px.

Comment: Definitely. It's not even like it's taking up more screen real estate for the average user, as it doesn't appear until it's clicked.

Comment: Chrome lets you can resize the comment box

Comment: Actually it will be any browser with CSS 3.0 support that should allow the resizing of text areas.

Comment: @Vincent Are you sure you aren't mixing up the comment and answer boxes? I can resize the answer box, but not the comment box.

Comment: @Macha - I can resize both in Chrome. I'd post a screen shot, but it's getting late & I'm just taking one last look at SO before shutting the machine down for the night.

Comment: use this bookmarklet to resize any textbox: http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/FormTextResizer/ or this Firefox addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8287

Answer (score 1):

Better yet, keep it small starting out, but then [make it grow as you type into it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477/autosizing-textarea)!

Answer (score 0):

Or, Stack Overflow could use the [`$.Resizable()`](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer) plugin (same thing they're using on Answers and Questions right now).