# Set a reasonable max-height for the comment textarea

Tags: feature-request, comments, design

Currently, the comment input textarea (`.js-comment-text-input` / `.comment-form>form textarea`) can be resized to be as long as you want. While I realize that this is a problem for exactly zero people, and has probably only been exercised by me for amusement purposes, I think it would be a nice quality of life improvement to set a reasonable `max-height`/`max-block-size` property value so that you can do a big mouse movement to resize and have it stop automatically at a reasonable place / once you get to a threshold of an unreasonable place.

Possible responses I have considered:

1. Considering that [comments currently can't have line breaks in them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197/997587), a reasonable minimum for the `max-value` could be estimated by filling a comment box with a wide character like "m" until the character limit is reached and then counting the number of lines, and then setting `max-height` based on that.

   While I'd like such a solution to work, there are a number of reasons why it won't.

   - It would work best by using the `lh` relative unit proposed by [css-values-4](https://www.w3.org/TR/2021/WD-css-values-4-20211216/#lh), which at this time is still in the working draft stage.
   - It doesn't take into account that the comment form automatically shrinks horizontally as needed when the viewport width shrinks (which- combined with word wrapping- means that such a max-height varies with viewport width)
   - The font-family isn't the same for all users.
2. Unscientifically pick a value that you think is sane / uncontroversial for most cases. There's always the `overflow: auto` to add a vertical scrollbar as needed.
3. Do nothing and let me continue to find simple joy in creating unnecessarily long comment textareas.

---

Topically loosely related: [Increase the height of the textarea for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11810/997587)

Comment: Currently, the user can adjust this to whatever they want. Some users (e.g. myself) want a comment textarea size which is larger than fits a single comment, because I *routinely* compose comments that are longer than the permitted length and then edit them down to what will actually fit. Given that the number of characters is shown just below the textarea, there's no functional reason to *force* the size to not be larger. While I'd probably support a *default* size to fit the length of a single comment, I oppose **forcing** the max size to not exceed the length of a single comment.